# How to get all messages from a blog in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to practice my syntax with rails.

I have 3 tables which is:

Blog:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
# Relationships
has_many :owners
has_many :posts
has_many :users, through: :owners
has_many :users_posts, through: :posts, source: :user

# Validations
validates :name, :description, presence: true
end
```

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relationships
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  # Validation
  validates :title, :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }

  # Update Method
  after_update :updated

  def updated
      puts "Got Updated"
  end
end
```

And Message:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  # Validation
  validates :author, :message, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
end
```

I'm trying with the terminal by `rails console`

and I'm trying to get all the messages from the blog id 5 by this command

`Blog.find(5).posts.messages`
it's not working but when I tried `Blog.find(5).posts.first.messages` => It showed me the message. 
So is there anyway I can get all the message from blog 5 in 1 command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

1) with an association. Add to blog

```
has_many :messages, through: :posts
```

and then

```
messages = Blog.find(5).messages
```

2) with a query, without a specific association for it

```
messages = Message.joins(post: :blog).where(blogs: { id: 5 })
```

Comment: my pleasure sir

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 more association to Blog class `has_many :messages, through: :posts`and then you'll be able to access `Blog.find(5).messages`